# google maps kml layer refresh problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, layer

I have a kml layer on my google maps app. I tried to refresh the kml layer by generating a new google.maps.KmlLayer object every 10s. The kml file contains customized icons. It works fine for the first several times of refreshing. However after a few minutes, the kml layer disappears (the icons disappear but they are still clickable). Any ideas why the kml layer disappears?

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
function initialize() {
        var p = new google.maps.LatLng(36.668419,-119.267578);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 5,
          center: p,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var kmllayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss'
          + '?key='
          + Math.random(),
          ({'preserveViewport': true}));
        geotaggingLayer.setMap(map);

        setInterval(refresh, 10000, kmllayer);
      }

      function refresh(layer) {

          var newkmllayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss'
            + '?key='
            + Math.random(),
            ({'preserveViewport': true}));
          layer.setMap(null);
          newkmllayer.setMap(map);
      }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just check the Firebug Net tab, you'll see that google is adding to the `lyrs` parameter with each request...until the request size becomes too large for the browser to handle.

Comment: I saw the lyrs parameter, but the request size won't be too large to handle.

Comment: As I said, monitor it...it's getting larger and larger with each call, so I guess the "length" was the problem...I really can't recall.

Comment: interested by the solution. Have you find one who is working?

Comment: this solution worked out for me as well, but as you said, the marker disappears after some time. has anyone found a solution?